# Rails Devise Confirmation Email Error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to setup an email confirmation for my User model for devise.  I'm not actually using devise for usernames and passwords and the such, I'm using Facebook authentication for sign-in/registration.  However, I need to get and confirm my users' emails after they sign up.

I tried things from many sources so far, but I'm still getting the error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol

Here's what I did so far:

## 1 Perform migration to add devise's confirmable relevant columns:

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :users, :email, :string
        add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
        add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
        add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    end
end
```

## 2 Tell the User model that we're using confirmable

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :confirmable
    ...
    #rest of model
    ...
end
```

## 3 Add email to config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = '<my_email_address>@gmail.com'
```

## 4 Add mailer info to config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'localhost:3000',
    user_name:            '<gmail_username>',
    password:             '<gmail_password>',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

## 5 Send email in the action:setup in the Users Controller

```
def setup
    user = current_user
    user.email = initial_setup_params[:email]
    if user.valid?
        user.save!
        user.send_confirmation_instructions
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer to this question mid-way through, but I figured I'd post anyway for my reference in the future and on the off chance anyone else had the same error.  Apparently, I had pasted the code from step 4 in the config/environment.rb file as well.  Idk if I misunderstood a tutorial or what, but I deleted that and now it works.